# How to get the contents of a page, as if it was visited in a browser?

Tags: php, url, curl

There was a certain URL I typed into my browser, and it displayed content, for example, `Hello.` But when I did a cURL request to that page, it didn't display `Hello.`, but instead displayed `Goodbye.` For example only.

So, would it be possible to display it as if it was in the browser?

I'm using PHP.

Comment: i suspect they don't want you  scraping the page, perhaps you should respect that.

Comment: @Dagon you should really just abide by their robots.txt

Comment: @peterpan and copyright and TOS and local law - don't  you think ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be happening for two reasons:

1. The server is detecting the user agent string, or is using cookies, try setting the curl user agent to what your browser is using.
2. The content is being set with javascript.

Comment: set the curl user agent to what your browser is using: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-curl-user-agent/